# White line above BottomTabNavigator in react-native

Tags: ios, react-native

I just started developing an app in react-native and added a bottom navigation. I then started styling the components and noticed a white line above the navigation, which i simply can't get rid of.

Picture of the Problem

[image]

Any idea on how to make that line have the same color as the background would be appreciated. It might be possible that the default background color behind the views is "shining through" since it's white and I have no idea how to change it. The app is only supposed to work on my own iPhone XR, so I'm not concerned about compatibility with android or other iPhone models

I'm a complete beginner regarding react-native, so bear with me here.
Here is my code so far:

**Navigation**

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Tab.Navigator
                tabBarOptions={{
                    activeTintColor: Colors.tabIconSelected,
                    inactiveTintColor: Colors.tabIconDefault,
                    style: styles.container
                }}>
                <Tab.Screen
                    name="Payments"
                    component={PaymentScreen}
                    options={{
                        tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name="logout"/>
                    }}/>
                <Tab.Screen
                    name="Income"
                    component={IncomeScreen}
                    options={{
                        tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name="login"/>
                    }}/>
            </Tab.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: Colors.darkBackgroundColor,
    }
});
```

**Payment View**

```
export default class PaymentScreen extends Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Payments!</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: Colors.backgroundColor,
    },
    text:{
        color: Colors.textColor
    }
});
```

Comment: I was literally going to ask that thank you !!! :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Edit:** the API has changed since I posted this answer. See the solution below if this one doesn't work for you

---

Figured it out myself after a bit of trial and error. The  `Tab.Navigator` class of the `NavigationContainer` has a prop called `tabBarOptions` which takes a stylesheet as its `style` option. And of course the border of the component can be changed here as well.

Here's the catch though: setting `borderWidth` to 0 does not hide the white border above the navigation. Only setting `borderTopWidth` to 0 has the desired effect.

So the full solution looks like this:

```
<NavigationContainer>
     <Tab.Navigator
         tabBarOptions={{
             activeTintColor: Colors.tabIconSelected,
             inactiveTintColor: Colors.tabIconDefault,
             style: styles.container
         }}/>
</NavigationContainer>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: Colors.darkBackgroundColor,
        borderTopWidth: 0
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can remove it in tabBarStyle in screenOption props likes below

```
 <Tab.Navigator 
      screenOptions={
            tabBarStyle:{borderTopWidth:0}
                     }
  />
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Comment: borderTopColor: "black", set this reduces the appearance, Again it depends on the background color

Answer (score 1):

**Using React Navigation 6.x**

In my case, I had to put the **tabBarStyle** on every `Tab.Screen` so for example:

```
<Tab.Screen name="HomeTab" component={xx} options={({ route }) => ({
    title: 'Home',
    tabBarStyle: {borderTop: 0},
})} />
<Tab.Screen name="SecondTab" component={xx} options={({ route }) => ({
    title: 'SecondTab',
    tabBarStyle: {borderTop: 0},
})} />
<Tab.Screen name="ThirdTab" component={xx} options={({ route }) => ({
    title: 'ThirdTab',
    tabBarStyle: {borderTop: 0},
})} />
```

Answer (score 0):

(unable to comment this answer as link is too much lengthy)

This line cannot be removed it seems. It'a coming by default when `BottomTab` is rendered to differentiate `BottomTab` and rest of the screen. Go through this [example](https://snack.expo.io/@syamkishore/9a92b3?platform=android&name=createBottomTabNavigator%20%C2%B7%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40%5E0.1.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative-stack%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%405.0.4%2Creact-native-gesture-handler%401.5.2%2Creact-native-reanimated%401.4.0%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%400.6.0%2Creact-native-screens%402.0.0-alpha.12&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F5.x%2Ftab-based-navigation-minimal.js) and try to apply multiple background colors for `BottomTab' then you will understand a bit clearly.

Answer (score 0):

in Bottom Tabs Navigator v6,
you can use tabBarStyle prop to resolve this white line issue.

make sure to gave the borderTopWidth:0,

```
screenOptions={({route}) =>({
    tabBarStyle: {
      height: IS_IPHONE ? RFValue(47) : RFValue(42),
      backgroundColor: AppTheme.colors.darkGrey,
      borderTopWidth: 0,
    },
}
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to this problem.

1. Go to node modules, look for the @react-navigation folder
2. Now open the bottom-tabs folder and then open the src folder
3. In the views folder, open the BottomTabBar.tsx
4. Go to styles at bottom and remove topBorderWidth property